# Wifi network with 130 Access Points

Tags: wifi

I am trying to figure out how to create a WiFi network on a 130 rooms hotel. I tried some Access Points on the hallways but the signal is not getting in the rooms as I desired...
 Now I am thinking to put 1 access point per room with POE. Is this something that can be done? Will the network work? There will be a lot of ip's (130 only from the AP's?) + the guests.

If anyone can give me some ideas I would much appreciate it!

Marius

Answer (score 0):

You can put a high power AP in the hallway and one AP working in repeater mode in each room to enlarge the signal.

Anyway, the best solution is put an AP in each room and connect them with network interface by line which is more stable.

Hope it helps. :)